# How to connect to github repository through jenkins?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I trying to connect git repos. through jenkins github plugin.
But I am getting following error under git repos entry field.

Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h git@github.com/sandipdivekar015505/Quest.git HEAD

**github project** - https://github.com/sandipdivekar015505/Quest

**git repos** - git@github.com/sandipdivekar015505/Quest.git

**repository** - Quest

I have installed all plugins created jenkins user and uploaded the ssh key then why I am getting this error?

Comment: Proxy? Does https://github.com/sandipdivekar015505/Quest without credentials work?

Comment: proxy i didn't get you ...
and for credentials i have created jenkins user on server and authenticated that with github using public key.
selecting that user in credentials field also.
don't know why exactly error is getting ?

Comment: Is your Jenkins behind a proxy? And do you even need authentication when it's an open project? A bit uncertain, but you could try without.

Comment: Go to Manage Plugins -> Advance and see if your proxy is defined (if needed).